# Data Analysis for a restaurant menu

Tags: database, powerbi, data-analysis, business-objects

I'm stuck in a project of creating a data analysis of the performance of the products sold in a restaurant.

I have:

1. the selling data base - product, qty sold per day, unit of the restaurant, shift - extracted via SAP Business Objects;
2. the menu data base - which products are currently in the menu in each unit of the restaurant - created by the restaurant unit based on the actual menu;
3. the products data base - which products are registered in the system and respective ids - extracted from the system.

All these data bases were extracted in .xlsx.

Now I don't know how to proceed, what are the next steps.
Anyone with a step-by-step guide of a similar project, or maybe interested in developing this project together?

The main objective is to publish this analysis in the Power BI to the C-level.

Comment: Build your model in powerbi by importing all necessary data into the star/snowflake schema based on what you need (business requirements);